# Spring MVC, Tiles 3, and Freemarker Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, tiles

I have integrated the Freemarker into an existing spring MVC and Tiles 3 application and found that it couldn't read the tiles definition file. It directly reads the content tile, which is one among 3 tiles that configured in the tiles definition file, bypassing the tile definition file. How can I make it to read the tiles definition file? Here are my codes:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tile-defs/view.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tile-defs/survey.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fmXmlEscape" class="freemarker.template.utility.XmlEscape"/>

<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="freemarkerVariables">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml_escape" value-ref="fmXmlEscape"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">3</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="freeMarkerViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

**tiles-def.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="template"
    template="/WEB-INF/views/main_template.ftl">
    <put-attribute name="header"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/header.ftl" />
    <put-attribute name="footer"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/footer.ftl" />
</definition>
<definition name="home" extends="template">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.ftl" />
</definition>
```

**main_template.ftl**

```
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />

    <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />

    <!-- Footer Page -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

</body>
```

**home.ftl**

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />



Hello world!  


<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<P>  ${message}. </P>
```

**header.ftl**

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />

This is header
```

Comment: [check out my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42979332/6116622)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding this to the top of my ftl files

`<#assign tiles=JspTaglibs["http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

and using

```
<@tiles.insertAttribute name="header" />
```

to insert something from the tiles definition.